# Load width transition when page gets to certain point in scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to trigger an animation through when the page is scrolled to a certain point. Here's what I have so far [(Codepen version)](http://codepen.io/arsdesign/pen/GpypQB):

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
 var hT = $('#photoshop').offset().top,
  hH = $('#photoshop').outerHeight(),
  wH = $(window).height(),
  wS = $(this).scrollTop();
 console.log((hT - wH), wS);
 if (wS > (hT + hH - wH)) {
  // I need the CSS to happen here, so it happens when the page is scrolled to "photoshop". //
 }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#photoshop {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #FF5444;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 24%;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  font-size: 80%;
}
/* this is what I need to happen when the page is scrolled to id="photoshop"

#photoshop {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #134;
  transition: ease-in 400ms;
  -moz-transition: ease-in 400ms;
  -webkit-transition: ease-in 400ms;
  transition-delay: 200ms;
}

*/
.percent {
  display: inline;
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 3px;
  font-size: 80%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="photoshop">
    <div class="percent">80%</div> photoshop
   </div>
</body>
```

I've tried doing a get element by ID function, but it won't load the css when I need it to. I don't know much about JavaScript and would like to do this with as little scripting as possible. Is there a way to change CSS after the `if (wS > (hT + hH - wH)) {` line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below,

You can use jQuery [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) method,

Just create a new class using **css** and apply that class using `addClass` method when the div is visible in the **viewport**

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var hT = $('#photoshop').offset().top,
    hH = $('#photoshop').outerHeight(),
    wH = $(window).height(),
    wS = $(this).scrollTop();
  console.log((hT - wH), wS);
  if (wS > (hT + hH - wH)) {
    $('#photoshop').addClass("photoshop_trans");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.dummy {
  height: 500px;
}
#photoshop {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #FF5444;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 24%;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  font-size: 80%;
}
/* this is what I need to happen when the page is scrolled to id="photoshop" */

#photoshop.photoshop_trans {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #134;
  transition: ease-in 400ms;
  -moz-transition: ease-in 400ms;
  -webkit-transition: ease-in 400ms;
  transition-delay: 200ms;
}
.percent {
  display: inline;
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 3px;
  font-size: 80%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="dummy"></div>
  <div id="photoshop">
    <div class="percent">80%</div>photoshop
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jquery `.css()` function ([see docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/)).  It takes a json object with the css properties and values you wish to apply.  So you would do something like this:

```
if (wS > (hT + hH - wH)) {
    $('#photoshop').css({
        'width': '40%',
        'background-color': '#134',
        'transition': 'ease-in 400ms',
        '-moz-transition': 'ease-in 400ms',
        '-webkit-transition': 'ease-in 400ms',
        'transition-delay': '200ms',
    });
}
```